# One of My domain is not working on "Google-Chrome"

Tags: g-suite, google

Since few days we are experiencing issue in one of a domain named "id-validation.us".
Google is blocking this domain on browsing from google-chrome. We tried to rectify the issue and found that google blocking all hits which is being done to id-validation.us. We are using a wild card certificate on this domain and certificate is fine as it is working well on rest of the domain. We tried to remove the code from web server as well but result is still same.

Google is throwing below error once you browse the website from google-chrome. Currently, an index.html file is placed on this web-server for this domain but response is same.

[image]

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/99020

Comment: They're probably (and rightly) suspicious of "id-validation.us" being used as a phishing site.